# Как обнулить DataSet - C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net

У меня есть метод для выполнения SQL запросов:

```
public static void Select(string mode, string[] attributes, string[] tables, string condition, string[] parameters, SqlDbType[] sqlDbType, Control[] control)
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + string.Join(", ", attributes) + " FROM " + string.Join(", ", tables) + " " + condition + " ", Action.ExecuteConnection());

            if (mode == "Single")
            {
                if (parameters == null || sqlDbType == null || control == null)
                {
                    sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameters[i], sqlDbType[i]).Value = control[i].Text;
                    }
                    sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                }
            } else if (mode == "Multiple")
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": Подгрузка данных из таблицы - [" + string.Join(", ", tables) + "]");
        }
```

Инициализация метода:

```
string[] parameters = { "@Username", "@Password" };
Command.Select("Single", new string[] { "EmployeeName", "UserSystem.UserPassword", "Position.PositionName" }, new string[] { "Employee" }, "INNER JOIN Position ON Employee.PositionID = Position.PositionID INNER JOIN UserSystem ON Employee.EmployeeID = UserSystem.EmployeeID WHERE Employee.EmployeeName =  " + parameters[0] + " AND UserSystem.UserPassword = " + parameters[1] + "", parameters, new SqlDbType[] { SqlDbType.NVarChar, SqlDbType.NVarChar }, new Control[] { comboBox_username, textBox_password });
```

Этот метод универсальный, если я хочу заполнить таблицу или получить данные по выборке и заполнить их в элемент управления, то для этого я вызываю этот метод. Но есть одна оплошность. У меня есть переменная:

```
public static DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
```

В которую заполняются данные полученные запросом. Метод работает, но если я после одной заполненной таблицы захочу тут же создать другую, то у меня сливаются две таблицы, то есть

> dataSet

Не обнуляется, а хранит старые данные. Как мне сделать этот метод универсальным, чтобы dataSet был свой для каждого экземпляра метода. Но также, я смог его вызвать из другого класса, для добавление например в

> control.DataSource

Надеюсь я достаточно доступно объяснил.

Comment: "Этот метод универсальный," - *Вы погубите себя, мой юный друг.* Дюма "Три мушкетера"

Comment: Что это значит? Этот метод ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНО универсальный

Comment: Это значит, что не с Вашим опытом писать универсальные инструменты.

Comment: Уверен, что поле `sqlDataReader` тоже статическое.

Comment: Ну я хотя бы стараюсь. Метод работает, он получает данные. Но это проблема с dataSet. Я хочу освободить себя от написания однотонного кода, в котором максимум, что может отличаться это значения введенные в запрос

Comment: Очистить датасет несложно: `dataSet.Tables.Clear();` Вопрос, к чему это приведет.

Comment: Я пробовал, но я до конца не понимаю, где мне его очищать?
 После инициализации метода или в самом методе? Насчёт пробовал... Я очищал dataset, но все отображаемые данные пропадали.

Comment: У меня есть tabControl, и ContextMenuStrip, при выборе нужной вкладочки, у меня создаётся tabPage и dataGridView с данными по выполненному запросу, если я не обнулю dataSet у меня две таблицы смешаются в один, если я захочу открыть ещё одну вкладочку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SelectResult : IDisposable
{
  public DataSet dataset { get; set; }
  public SqlDataReader reader { get; set; }

  // TODO: implement IDisposable to dispose dataset/reader if they are not null
}

public static SelectResult Select(...)
{
  SelectResult result = new SelectResult();

    ...
    result.reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    ...

    ...
    result.dataset = new DataSet();
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(result.dataset);
    ...

  return result;
}

using (SelectResult result = ClassWithStaticSelectMethod.Select(...))
{
  // use result.dataset or result.reader
}
```

Comment: Заработало, только мне пришлось ещё это дописать void IDisposable.Dispose() {}